# How do I exit and external CMD file from a Node-Webkit Application?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, node-webkit

I have a Batch script `run.cmd` witch is in the same `dir` of the Node-WebKit app. I would like to run `run.cmd` `onClick` of a button from within the Node-Webkit application. I have tried several different snippets i found online but I cant seam to figure it out...

```
<button onclick="runHelperProcess()">Run Process</button>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runHelperProcess() {
        gui.Shell.openItem('run.cmd');
    }
</script>
```

^^^ This is as close as I've gotten and it still wont work. When i do this it opens another instance of the Node-Webkit app and uses the `.cmd` file as a text file and displays the files text instead of running it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is no one able to help?

Answer (score 0):

That's just impossible. You can't stop an external process from nw.js, or you'll have to make your own C++ addon which will interact with other processes (very complicated because you have to interact with the js application and the process, then return events...).